# Synchronously call function with return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, return

I am trying to make a translate helper in my express node.js app.
I have already made a handlebars helper that works pretty fine on *views*, but I'm trying to make one that will work in my *controllers*.
I want it to be **synchronous**.

I don't want this:

```
helpers.Translator('keyWord1', 'en', function(err, word){
    return res.render("page", { word: word });
});
```

I want this:

```
var word = helpers.Translator('keyWord1', 'en');
return res.render("page", { word: word });
```

The reason is because I want to get the word as a string so I can return it back to page as json, when handling errors on ajax POST/GET:

```
var error = helpers.Translator('keyWord2', 'en');
return res.json({OK:false, error: error});
```

Sometimes I need to return multiple translated words, and I definitely **do not** want to do this:

```
helpers.Translator('keyWord1', 'en', function(err, word1){
    helpers.Translator('keyWord2', 'en', function(err, word2){
        helpers.Translator('keyWord3', 'en', function(err, word3){
            return res.render("page", { word1: word1, word2: word2, word3:word3 });
        });
    });
});
```

How should my helper Translator look like?

Comment: The solution to this is well known. Promises.

Comment: Either you can use async/await in nodejs 8+

Comment: Promise all is a solution

Comment: I tried doing something like this:
https://pastebin.com/hRNs9X2N
Didn't work. Tips/help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to make `helpers.Translator` a new promise, something like:

```
Translator (keyword, lng) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
    resolve()
    reject()
  })
}
```

so, when you are calling the helper you can do something like this using async/await:

```
async function myFunction () {
  try {
    const word = await helpers.Translator('keyWord1', 'en');
    const word2 = await helpers.Translator('keyWord2', 'en');
    return res.render("page", { word, word2 }); // this is equal to ("page", { word: word, word2: word2 })
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Conclusion: I wasn't adding await before Translator, and also I didn't make a function, in which scope I was using await, async. Thank you, again.